# Linear Layout weights not working inside of Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-layout-weight

Myself and a few friends are making a game for android that has a field of play. In front of a portion of the field of play, I want to place buttons. Like so:

[image]

In order to put one set of xml in front of another, I believe we need to use a Relative Layout. So far we have been doing this inline (programatically) but now I want to do this using XML. I think I have a pretty good understand of how weighting works. I am doing this using linear layouts inside of one another. The intended result is to have the buttons only cover a small portion of the screen.

Unfortunately, when I add my linear layout to my relative layout, the weighting functionality doesn't seem to work anymore.

For clarity, I have added two rows of buttons and weighted the second row to be larger than the first. Here is the Android Studio preview of what the layout should look like:

[image]

Here is what it is actually coming out as:

[image]

The two rows are being displayed as the same size. I am hoping someone can give me an answer as to why this is happening, and if possible, a solution as to how to fix the problem.

Here is my code adding the linear layout to the Relative layout:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.testLayout);
View  view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.testgameplay_wrapper, null);
relativeLayout.addView(view);
```

Here is the relevant XML. I have created a wrapper class to simplify things:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/testScreenLinearWrapper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/testgameplay_buttondisplay"></include>

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/testgameplay_buttondisplay"></include>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

testgamplaybutton_buttondisplay.xml as requested:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/testScreenButtonDisplay"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInnermost1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <include
                layout="@layout/defend_screen_buttons"></include>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInnermost2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <include
                layout="@layout/test_screen_buttons"></include>

        </LinearLayout>
```

test_screen_buttons.xml as will likely be requested:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/testScreenButtons"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/spawnCreepButton"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_button"
    android:text="Spawn Creep"
    android:onClick="RunProjectileTest"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendCreepsButton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_button"
    android:text="Send Creeps"
    android:onClick="StartSendCreepsScreen"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/replayButton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_button"
    android:text="Replay"
    android:onClick="StartReplayScreen"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

defend_screen_buttons.xml as will likely be requested:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/buttonViewGroup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_button"
    android:text="Start" />

    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/basic_button"
    android:text="Prepare Attack!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you see why I tried to simplify it XD

Thanks for your time and expertise!

Comment: Post your `testgameplay_buttondisplay`

Comment: I think you forgot to give android:weightSum  to layout whose android:id="@+id/testScreenLinearWrapper"

Comment: Please post your *testgameplay_buttondisplay.xml* file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found an answer to my problem.

Here is my old code which was creating the LinearLayout and adding it to the RelativeLayout:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.testLayout);
View  view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.testgameplay_wrapper, null);
relativeLayout.addView(view);
```

Here is my new code:

```
    //Now using LinearLayout instead of View     
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.testgameplay_buttondisplay, null);

    //convert dp to pixels
    int height = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    //Set the height of the layout in newly calculated pixels
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);

    relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
```

As you can see, I am making use of LayoutParams and adding them to my linearLayout. The buttons now appear on the screen as I want them to and their size varies depending on the pixel height I indicate. Thanks to all those who gave their input!

Answer (score 1):

In your outermost LinearLayout tag, control the `android:layout_height` attribute. Because it is set to match_parent for now, it takes the entire screen. Set it to some absolute number (e.g. 200dp) and you should see the difference.

Comment: I'm trying to get the buttons to only take up a certain percentage of the screen. A percentage which remains constant independent of screen resolution (different phones). I assumed dp was a measurement of pixels, but after looking, it appears that dp has some dependence on the screen resolution. It seems it will scale depending on what type of phone the user is using. Assuming this, I think this is the answer I am looking for. I'll have to try it out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this link http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html and you should be able to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with relative layouts that were inside a linear layout and the deviation from the center can be a problem. I check all the solutions and I did not see anyone who used `match_parent` on `layout_width` for the child of the linear view. Change `0dp` and `wrap_content` to `match_parent`. Here is a before and after in my problem: [image]

Comment: Thank you awesome stranger. Your answer saved me a lot of struggle.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use the layout_weight property in a child View, you need to specify the [weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) of the parent View. This works with LinearLayouts.
In the example below, I've declared a root LinearLayout, with a weightSum of 1, and a child view which layout_weight equals .5, so that this will fill half of the screen. 
This child view (wrapper) has a weightSum of 1.5, and inside of it has two child views, one with a layout_weight equals .5, and the other one width a layout_weight equals 1. Note that these LinearLayouts have a weightSum equals 1, so that each button inside should have a layout_weight equals .2, for an evenly distribution.

Hope this helps!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <!-- Wrapper id View fills half of the screen, 0.5 and has a weightSum of 1.5-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:weightSum="1.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, my issue seems to stem from the combination of using a Linear Layout inside of a Relative Layout. I have successfully been able to use weighting with Linear Layouts in the past without using weightsum. I tried setting the weightsum with my issue and it did not help.